# Возможно ли программно нажать на кнопку расположенную на web сайте

Tags: java, android

Такой вопрос:
Возможно ли программно нажать на кнопку расположенную на web сайте, у сайта нет api ,есть только форма и сама кнопка:

```
 <div class="ckBtnCon">
                <input name="submit_bt" id="submit_bt" type="submit" value="Отправить"  />
        &nbsp;
    </div>
```

т.е программно я собираюсь заполнять нужные поля в форме, а как нажать программно на кнопку?
т.е заполнил пользователь форму в приложение и нажал нa кнопку,данные передаются в форму на сайте и потом должно происходить нажатие кнопки на этом же сайте

Comment: [Уже есть много ответов на данный вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30113445/how-to-perform-a-button-click-inside-a-webview-android).

Answer (score 1):

Для этого есть метод `click()`:

```
document.getElementById('submit_bt').click()
```

Comment: не встречал...для андройда такое

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно воспользоваться сниффером (анализатором трафика) и посмотреть, что происходит (куда и какой запрос отправляется) при нажатии кнопки. Далее можно осуществить этот запрос непосредственно в Вашем приложении.